# With SVN, is it possible to manage a repository within a repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

I am creating a website stored in a SVN repository. Under my `/lib/vendor/` directory, I want to be able to checkout and update to the latest version of Symfony from its SVN repository.

However, when I do this, I am unable to commit the `/lib/vendor/` directory because it is already under separate version control.

Is it possible to maintain a separate repository within a repository?

Comment: Yo dawg, we heard you like repositories..

Comment: @The Communist Duck Not even recursive :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an External.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

and a little more on the how-to side...

http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/132-svnexternals.html

Answer (score 1):

SVN is not ... well known for this. There is `svn:external`, which works well for "pulls" but not really for anything else IMOHO.

There is [Piston](http://www.yup.com/articles/2006/11/01/better-subversion-external-branch-management-with-piston) and [Braid](http://ropiku.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/installing-rspec-with-braid/) which are external "wrappers". I didn't have any luck with them when I tried ~year ago: they have Python and/or Ruby dependencies, and they seem mostly dated/abandoned -- but it could be worth looking into.

With SVN I just "gave in" and now use as many repositories as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's sort of possible.  [See svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/svn-book.html#svn-ch-7-sect-3).

Basically it allows you to checkout a revision of another pedwinroject as a subdirectory in yours.  You can update the revision referenced and the update is traced in your primary project.